# Cassandra copy table into doesn't produce output

Tags: cassandra-2.1

I want to copy the data of my table into a csv file. But it never writes a single row. It just creates a 0B file and the process looks to be simply hung in the CQLSH terminal.

If I end this through `^c`, it just prints

```
copy emp(empid,empname) to 'emp1.csv';
Using 1 child processes

Starting copy of ea_sc_ww_elf.emp with columns [empid, empname].
IOError:
IOError:
IOError:
IOError:
IOError:
IOError:
IOError:
IOError:
IOError:
```

Any configuration causing this ???

Please note: for testing, I created a simple employee table with 2 rows of data and only `2 columns empid, empname`.

Answer (score 1):

I Re-installed Cassandra in a different server and tried to export the data into csv, It worked fine.
All I can guess is this Might be related to some setting in `cassandra.yaml` with any of the below properties:

- rpc_address
- broadcast_rpc_address

I haven't got free time to experiment on this. I will leave a confirmation when I do.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run cqlsh with "–debug" flag. You will have more detailed information, thath helps in troubleshooting.